# In javascript, how can I click on link programmatically in case href="javascript:someMethod()" without JQuery

Tags: javascript

I have a link on the page with `href="javascript:someMethod()"`. I need to click on this link programmatically within javascript. without using eval() and Without JQuery please.

Comment: Try to use <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="someMethod();"> and then you call click() as usual in javascript.

Comment: Why can't you just set an id on your link then target the id with your javascript.

Comment: I cannot change the html file. So, I need to detect the link and simulate as if the user press the link

Answer (score 1):

You can assign an id to the link and use the following, or just call `someMethod()` directly.

```
document.getElementById('idOfLink').click();
```

Comment: First of all, I have no control over the html file to modify it. also, .click() function doesn't work for href with javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

Assign a class or a id to the element.

```
<a id="link">Click me</a>
```

Attach the click event to the link.

```
var link = document.getElementById("link");

link.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
   // Prevent the default action.

   e.preventDefault();
   // Do something else;

});
```